# Pointer to list element after removal

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I have a list that stores objects.

```
list<MyObject> l;
```

I also have a method that returns a pointer to one of those objects, if it exists, or nullptr otherwise.

```
MyObject* get(int x) {
    for (std::list<MyObject>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->X == x) {
            return &(*it);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

If I get() a pointer to an element, and while I am using it, it gets erased from another thread, the pointer becomes invalid, and weird things happen :)

What I wanted to know is if there is a way of returning some special kind of pointer in get(), so that if I call erase on an element and that element is still being referenced, its memory won't be released until the pointer to it goes out of scope.

I considered using a reference, but I need the possibility of returning nullptr on get, so I can check from the caller if the return was indeed a valid object.

Can someone suggest a better way of doing this, to avoid these memory issues?

Comment: A list of `shared_ptr`s will be better for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended you should use some smart_pointer to manage the shared ownership.

Some recomendations:

- Use always as default, [std::vector](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#list)
- If could use C++11 use the standard shared_ptr for shared ownership, if not, use boost version.
- Use the [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header as much as you can (in this case [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is the right one).

You should also try to use the algorithm for the search of the specific element. Here is some sample code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct MyObject {
    int X;
    MyObject(int x_value) : X(x_value) {}
};

using element_t = std::shared_ptr<MyObject>;

std::vector<element_t> l{
    std::make_shared<MyObject>(3), std::make_shared<MyObject>(4),
    std::make_shared<MyObject>(5), std::make_shared<MyObject>(6),
    std::make_shared<MyObject>(7), std::make_shared<MyObject>(8)};

element_t get(int x) {
    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(l), std::end(l),
                           [x](const element_t& elem) { return elem->X == x; });

    element_t found;
    if (it != std::end(l)) {
        found = *it;
    }
    return found;
}

int main() {
    auto f1 = get(6);
    if (f1) {
        std::cout << "encontrado " << f1->X << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "6 no se encontro" << std::endl;
    }

    auto f2 = get(10);
    if (f2) {
        std::cout << "encontrado " << f2->X << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "10 no se encontro" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the new features of C++ that taking me time to set

Comment: I am not using vector as the list has removes at random positions, and the remove is faster than on the vector. can this be done in list as well? I never used shared_ptr, I will look into it.

Comment: can I return a null shared_ptr?

Comment: With respect to the vector, read the link, in benchmark commented by Bjarne Stroustrup, removing element in the middle of the `vector` out perform `list`, until 500'000 elements, probably more, that of course depend of the element (is the copy expensive?, the move? etc...). Yes the default constructed `shared_ptr` is nullptr initialized. In this case if `it != std::end(l)`, __found__ would contain nullptr.

Comment: Code updated as function, and added found and not-found examples.

Comment: In this case, don't use `vector`. **Never** use `std::list` unless you can actually articulate a reason why you should. Use a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)`< int, shared_ptr<MyObject> >` where the `int` is `MyObject::X` It will be much faster, cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

Before using smart pointers, you might want to make sure you can spell out the reason why you can't (or don't want to) design a system where your objects have only one owner at a given time.

Smart pointers will avoid invalid data access, but they have all sorts of more or less hidden problems

- they cost additional memory, force you to use them and their move semantics everywhere, and might easily become tricky, e.g. if you keep circular references or want an object to return a smart pointer to itself,
- `std::` containers become basically as useless as when you fill them with any kind of pointers (a vector of pointers is not a vector of objects),
- you don't control where the deallocation takes place, so you might have your objects deleted by any task referencing them, possibly a time-critical one,
- having no clear idea of who owns what is more often than not a recipe for disaster.

For instance, having one thread decide to delete objects while another grabs some from the same storage without any synchronization is very dangerous indeed. It is a bit as if one thread considered the object invalid while the other would consider it valid.
Does not strike me as the most robust design, but surely you have your reasons.

I think you could start by using `unique_ptr`s and see if that suits your needs, instead of jumping to `shared_ptr`s right away.

Comment: I actually prefer not using shared_ptr nor unique_ptr, as memory and speed are quite critical, so I will have another go at my current design, trying to sync everything at the place where I am having that specific issue. thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: `unique_ptr` has no runtime overhead. It just forces you to explicitely transfer ownership, which makes for a more robust design without hampering performances.